# about square elements in finite field

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

q is power of odd prime.How to show that  $-1$ is square in $\mathbb{F_q}$ if $ q=1(mod4)$ i.e order of field divide 4 and -1 is not square if $ q=3(mod4)$.

I know that since q is power of odd prime;  order of $\mathbb{F_q}^*$ is $q-1$ and its cyclic group of even order. I also know only element of order 2 there is -1. Then how to proceed for both this claims?

Comment: Take $a=-1$ in the duplicate. It says that $a$ is a square iff $a^{(q-1)/2}=1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde so in square class group square element becomes 1 ,right?